# Why is my MySQL Decimal column rounding prematurely?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

I am attempting to store large decimal values with a precision of (27,18) in a MySQL database (v5.6). With very small decimal numbers, the precision works as expected. However, when the first significant figure is three or fewer left of the decimal point. The database will round the number off. Is it possible to store decimal numbers like this within a MySQL database with full precision?

Examples:

- 56789.296627640550656375 rounds to 56789.2966276406
- 0.886791857600000798 rounds to 0.886791857600001
- 0.000000000000000001 does not round
- 0.000005000000000001 does not round
- 0.005000000000000001 rounds to 0.05

Comment: Where are these strings coming from? Are you typing them in your select query?

Comment: "What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic" https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html ..

Comment: @SalmanA these specific strings I was inserting manually as an example. However, there are also strings being inserted by a PHP application and they also do the same thing.

Comment: @Jonr it is weird if you were inserting them manually. No rounding here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=196a89239d77015f034e8d9cccd9b24a. PHP might round though e.g. if you do a `->query("SELECT " . 0.000005000000000001 . " AS val")`.

Comment: @SalmanA thanks for your insights - it got me onto the right track. The DB itself was storing data at the correct precision. However my SQL client was itself was rounding the numbers, both when viewing and inserting the values - so I wasn't getting a true representation of what was happening. I moved to using the CLI to query the database and all was well.

Comment: @jonr get rid of that client and file a bug report!